# Cannot click on the button inside span based on the text in sibling Protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I'm trying to click on a button based on the sibling text.

```
<li ng-repeat="list in lists" ng-if="!includes(list)" class="ng-scope">
    <span class="ng-binding">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="useList(list)">Use</button>
        test
    </span>
    <span class="ng-binding">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="useList(list)">Use</button>
        test2
    </span>
</li>
```

As shown in the above code, based on test or test2 I want to click on the button accordingly. How can I achieve that?

Comment: This is the second such questions you have in a short space of time. Can you include the effort you have made to locate the elements yourself in the question?

Comment: @DublinDev Yes—I provided a viable answer both times, but OP “couldn’t get it to work” last time and seems to be ignoring my answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I'll write some code that takes takes a variable `myText` and clicks the button; this should work no matter how many span elements you repeat as long as they are in the format shown in your question.

```
let buttons = element.all(by.css('button'));
for (var button in buttons) {
    WebElement parent = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                               "return arguments[0].parentNode;", button);
    if (parent.getText() == myText) {button.click()};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
 select(text:string){
   const ele = element.all(by.css('li > span > button');
   for(i=0;i< ele.count();i++){
   if(ele.get(i).getText() === text){
     ele.get(i).click();
      }
    }
```

Pass the value of the button you wish to click to the above function.

Hope it helps you

Comment: OP is not wanting to find and click buttons based on the text of the button itself but rather based on the text of the button’s parent *span* element.